# Highlight found text if it is a complete word, count separation of repeated words, process selected text

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlight

I need to highlight words in a document and show some clues on distances between them. I've this program that I assembled from different pieces.

```
Sub RepeatedWordsShow()

    Const maxwords = 9000                               'Maximum words allowed
    Dim SingleWordA As String                       'Raw word pulled from doc
    Dim SingleWordR As String               'Raw word to compare
    Dim RepeatedWords(maxwords) As String       'Array to hold repeated words
    Dim RepeatedWordsDistances(maxwords) As Integer 'Distances of words
    Dim rwnum As Integer                'counter for repeated word list
    Dim worddistance As Integer             'Temporary variable
    Dim countWord As Integer                'Actual word
    Dim thisWord As Integer             'Actual comparing word
    Dim ttlwds As Long                                  'Total words in the document
    Dim Excludes As String                              'Words to be excluded
    Dim Found As Boolean                'Temporary flag
    Dim j, k As Integer                         'Temporary variables

    ' Set up excluded words
    Excludes = "[a][an][and][at][for][from][he][her][his][in][of][on][she][the][to][was]"

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    System.Cursor = wdCursorWait
    ttlwds = ActiveDocument.Words.Count

    rwnum = 0
    countWord = 0
    thisWord = 0

    For Each aword In ActiveDocument.Words
        SingleWordA = Trim(LCase(aword))
        'Out of range?
        If SingleWordA < "a" Or SingleWordA > "z" Then
            SingleWordA = ""
        End If
        'On exclude list?
        If InStr(Excludes, "[" & SingleWordA & "]") Then
            SingleWordA = ""
        End If
        If Len(SingleWordA) > 0 Then
            For Each rword In ActiveDocument.Words
                SingleWordR = Trim(LCase(rword))
                If SingleWordR < "a" Or SingleWordR > "z" Then
                    SingleWordR = ""
                End If
                If InStr(Excludes, "[" & SingleWordR & "]") Then
                    SingleWordR = ""
                End If
                If Len(SingleWordR) > 0 Then
                    If SingleWordR = SingleWordA Then
                        If thisWord <> countWord Then
                           RepeatedWords(rwnum) = SingleWordR
                           worddistance = thisWord - countWord
                           RepeatedWordsDistances(rwnum) = worddistance
                           rwnum = rwnum + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            thisWord = thisWord + 1
            Next rword
            thisWord = 0

        End If
        ttlwds = ttlwds - 1
        StatusBar = "Remaining: " & ttlwds
        countWord = countWord + 1
    Next aword

    'Highlights and Underlines words

    k = 0
    For Each itm In RepeatedWords
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.HomeKey wdStory, wdMove
        Selection.Find.Execute itm
        Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
            'Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineDotted
            If RepeatedWordsDistances(k) > 0 And RepeatedWordsDistances(k) < 6 Then
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineDouble
            End If
            If RepeatedWordsDistances(k) > 5 And RepeatedWordsDistances(k) < 11 Then
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
            End If
            If RepeatedWordsDistances(k) > 10 And RepeatedWordsDistances(k) < 21 Then
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineDash
            End If
            If RepeatedWordsDistances(k) > 20 And RepeatedWordsDistances(k) < 51 Then
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineDotted
            End If
            Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
            Selection.Find.Execute
        Loop
    k = k + 1
    Next

    'Now report the results
    'tmpName = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName
    'Documents.Add Template:=tmpName, NewTemplate:=False
    'Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.ClearAll
    'With Selection
    '    For j = 1 To rwnum
    '        .TypeText Text:=Trim(Str(RepeatedWordsDistances(j))) _
    '          & vbTab & RepeatedWords(j) & vbCrLf
    '    Next j
    'End With

    System.Cursor = wdCursorNormal

End Sub
```

The objective is to highlight the repeated words (now in turquoise), and underline the words according to various ranges of distances from their occurrences (double line to nearest words, dots to far).

This solution has some problems:

1) The last block: 'Highlights and underlines words' processes words inside words. t marks "light" in "highlighting", as an example, if light is marked as a repeated word in the obtained list (RepeatedWords). How I can avoid that?

2) The distance number counts commas, dots and semicolons from the text, even if they do not appear in the list. The last commented section generates a report to see that.

3) How can the user, after that macro is done, perform an action over a marked word (double-right click, middle click, triple click, something like that, and the same words of that occurrence then highlights with another color (yellow) to identify them?

See it in action [image: See it in action]

Answer (score 0):

1) There are [many options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193977.aspx) for the `Find.Execute` method. `MatchWholeWord` is probably what you're looking for. I'd recommend setting your options before executing, such as in this example taken from the MSDN site

```
With Selection.Find 
    .ClearFormatting 
    .MatchWholeWord = True 
    .MatchCase = False 
    .Execute FindText:="library" 
End With
```

2) [Punctuation and paragraph marks in a document are included in the Words collection.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836346.aspx)
Since you are counting manually you could just exclude the punctuation manually. It's a bit messy but the quickest fix I can think of. Something like

```
If Instr(".,;:!?...", SingleWordR) = 0 Then thisWord = thisWord + 1 'would have to put all punctuation character inside the string
```

or

```
If SingleWordR Like "[!a-zA-Z]" Then thisWord = thisWord + 1 'this would not include special characters though
```

**edit:** This would also have to be done with `countword`

3) Apparently a selection change event [is possible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192791.aspx) but an easier way might be to write a macro that checks if the current selection is highlighted and highlights other occurrences, then assign a key command to it (through the word options). The same macro could also be used to recolor the words to turquoise (would have to be run again by the user).

---

I'm not sure about your highlighting and distance counting though. You store each word that appears more than once and the distance to each of the other occurences. So your array for a text like "a b b a b" would look like this

```
a  3
b  1
b  3
a -3
b -1
b  2
b -3
b -2
```

Then you highlight all the occurences of each entry based on the second column. That would mean that the only relevant value is the last (positive), in this case 2 for a and 2 for b. It can be seen with "day" in your example. The first two occurrences are less then 21 apart are underlined dotted.

You are also looping through all the words for every word. That means (number of words)*(number of words) iterations. You should at least stop once thisword-countword > 50.

Maybe another approach would be to look ahead of each word by 5, 10, 20, 50 words and highlight all the other occurrences (and the word itself) if found.

Comment: I don't know if this is right but I'm posting the improvements with your recommendation in another answer, to put the code.

Comment: It's only right if the improvements solved the problem (in which case it isn't really necessary). If there are new problems that would be an edit to the question or a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I've come with this:

```
Sub RepeatedWordsShow()
    Const maxwords = 9000                               'Maximum unique words allowed
    Dim SingleWordA As String                           'Raw word pulled from doc
    Dim SingleWordR As String
    Dim RepeatedWords(maxwords) As String
    Dim RepeatedWordsDistances(maxwords) As Integer
    Dim rwnum As Integer
    Dim worddistance As Integer
    Dim countWord As Integer
    Dim thisWord As Integer
    Dim ttlwds As Long                      'Total words in the document
    Dim Excludes As String                  'Words to be excluded
    Dim Found As Boolean                    'Temporary flag
    Dim j, k As Integer                     'Temporary variables

    ' Set up excluded words
    Excludes = "[a][an][and][at][for][from][he][her][his][in][of][on][she][the][to][was][with]"


    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    System.Cursor = wdCursorWait
    ttlwds = ActiveDocument.Words.Count

    rwnum = 0
    countWord = 0
    thisWord = 0

    For Each aword In ActiveDocument.Words
        SingleWordA = Trim(LCase(aword))
        'Out of range?
        If SingleWordA < "a" Or SingleWordA > "z" Then
            SingleWordA = ""
        End If
        'On exclude list?
        If InStr(Excludes, "[" & SingleWordA & "]") Then
            SingleWordA = ""
            countWord = countWord + 1
        End If
        'If word is valid, compare with all words
        If Len(SingleWordA) > 0 And SingleWordA Like "[a-zA-Z]*" Then
            'Comparing
            countWord = countWord + 1
            For Each rword In ActiveDocument.Words
                SingleWordR = Trim(LCase(rword))
                If SingleWordR < "a" Or SingleWordR > "z" Then
                    SingleWordR = ""
                End If
                If InStr(Excludes, "[" & SingleWordR & "]") Then
                    SingleWordR = ""
                    thisWord = thisWord + 1
                End If
                If Len(SingleWordR) > 0 And SingleWordR Like "[a-zA-Z]*" Then
                    thisWord = thisWord + 1
                    If SingleWordR = SingleWordA Then
                        If thisWord <> countWord Then
                           RepeatedWords(rwnum) = SingleWordR
                           worddistance = thisWord - countWord
                           RepeatedWordsDistances(rwnum) = Abs(worddistance)
                           rwnum = rwnum + 1
                           'Debug.Print "Repeated Word:" + RepeatedWords(rwnum) + "  Distance:" + Str(RepeatedWordsDistances(rwnum))
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next rword
            thisWord = 0

        End If
       ttlwds = ttlwds - 1
       StatusBar = "Remaining: " & ttlwds

    Next aword


    'Highlighs and Underlines words

    k = 0
    For Each itm In RepeatedWords
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.MatchWholeWord = True
        Selection.HomeKey wdStory, wdMove
        Selection.Find.Execute itm
        Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
            If RepeatedWordsDistances(k) > 0 And RepeatedWordsDistances(k) < 6 Then
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineDouble
            End If
            If RepeatedWordsDistances(k) > 5 And RepeatedWordsDistances(k) < 11 Then
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
            End If
            If RepeatedWordsDistances(k) > 10 And RepeatedWordsDistances(k) < 21 Then
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineDash
            End If
            If RepeatedWordsDistances(k) > 20 Then
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineDotted
            End If
            Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
            Selection.Find.Execute
        Loop
    k = k + 1
    Next

    'Now write out the results
    'tmpName = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName
    'Documents.Add Template:=tmpName, NewTemplate:=False
    'Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.ClearAll
    'With Selection
    '    For j = 1 To rwnum
    '        .TypeText Text:=Trim(Str(RepeatedWordsDistances(j))) _
    '          & vbTab & RepeatedWords(j) & vbCrLf
    '    Next j
    'End With

    'Write results in immediate window
    For j = 1 To rwnum
     Debug.Print "Repeated Word:" + RepeatedWords(j) + "  Distance:" + Str(RepeatedWordsDistances(j))
    Next j

    System.Cursor = wdCursorNormal
End Sub
```

To your answer, arcadeprecinct:

1) I have implemented this, that was exactly what I needed (sorry, I'm not an experienced programmer) `.MatchWholeWord = True` works as expected.

2) I implemented this, too. The expression `Like "[a-zA-Z]*"` works very well.

3) Let me explain, the reason what I'm doing this is because I'm writing in spanish, and I've observed this is a frequent problem with writing. I have to check and recheck my text and sometimes is difficult to spot repeated words. Some repetitions are intentional, some are not. I've tried some software, Scrivener only reports text statistics but I have to close the report and search manually all the occurrences. MSWord only counts words. ProWritingAid does a very good job but still the text has to be pasted in their box. Notepad++ has a feature: when you click any word, it highlights all the same words in the same text, but still I have to make the corrections in the original text, losing all formatting. My macro helps me to work directly on the text, a combo of ProWritingAid and Notepad++.

So I'll look forward to:

a) Highlight the same words with a special click on one. Highlighting tells me "this word is repeated, 2 or more times" (it would be nice to implement color code for ranges of occurrences). The Underline feature works like: the heaviest underlined is the nearest repetition, is easier to spot it with that method. It depends to me as a writer to preserve the word or not.

b) To give a context to work with: Document, Section or Paragraph. Obviously, my macro will be difficult to use in a document of a greater number of words, so as you say, I'll try to put the limits to sections only, or a limited number of words. If I use this in a long, long file, it could hang or crash the system.

I solved the issue of the "negative distances" with `Abs(worddistance)`.

Anyway, I'll give a try to another approach, as you say, because I agree that my code is inefficient. My interest is to heavily underline the nearest words. Distanced duplications are least important, but it finally has to mark every duplicated word. Can you help me to improve the code in the main For-Each block? The objective is: any given distance between two identical words, the one that matters is the lesser one, so it'll have to mark the words with the heaviest underline (Double), even if other occurrences of that words are far.

Am I allowed to keep posting my future editions in this thread? I'm new to this.

Thank you very much for the valuable help!

**edit:** You said

> "Maybe another approach would be to look ahead of each word by 5, 10,
>   20, 50 words and highlight all the other occurrences (and the word
>   itself) if found."

I agree with this, but looking ahead until the end of the text, highlighting all the occurrences, the word itself, and storing only the lesser distance for the underlines. That would be nice but at this moment I have no idea how to search from the actual word to forward. I'll figure it out or you can give me a clue.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct Another update, I've tried my inefficient code and it took 15 minutes! to process 2570 words. Not the better solution, obviously. Now I know that I don't need too much words revised, only the "neighbor" words up to 150 or 200 in distance.